# Align two elements next to / besides / inline with each other in <View/> react native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, view

How would I align two items (icon/text) next to each other?

```
<TouchableOpacity
        key = {index}
        onPress = {() => this._onPress(key)}
        style = {containerStyle.container}>
        <View>
          <Icon 
            name = {Platform.OS === "ios" ? "ios-checkmark-outline" : "md-checkmark"}
            size = {24}
            style = {{ paddingLeft: 10, color: "#108EE9"}} /> 
          <Text 
            style = {this._createStyleText(key)}>
          {key}
          </Text>
        </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>

const containerStyle = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 8,
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
  },
}); 

const textStyle = StyleSheet.create({
  unselectedText: {
      paddingLeft: 45,
      color: "#000000",
      fontWeight: "normal",
  },

});
```

Right now the are aligned like this:

```
icon
       text
```

I need them to be like this

```
icon  text
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [flexDirection](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html#flex-direction) to layout items in row. The default is column

```
<TouchableOpacity
  key = {index}
  onPress = {() => this._onPress(key)}
  style = {containerStyle.container}>
  <View style={containerStyle.rowContainer}>
    <Icon
      name = {Platform.OS === "ios" ? "ios-checkmark-outline" : "md-checkmark"}
      size = {24}
      style = {{ paddingLeft: 10, color: "#108EE9"}} />
    <Text
      style = {this._createStyleText(key)}>
      {key}
    </Text>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>

const containerStyle = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 8,
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
  },
  rowContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row'
  }
}); 

const textStyle = StyleSheet.create({
  unselectedText: {
      paddingLeft: 45,
      color: "#000000",
      fontWeight: "normal",
  },

});
```

Comment: Actually, the default is `row`

Comment: Not on react native

Comment: React Native, default is column. More info here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox

Answer (score 4):

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
  <Icon
    name = {Platform.OS === "ios" ? "ios-checkmark-outline" : "md-checkmark"}
    size = {24}
    style = {{ paddingLeft: 10}} />
  <Text
    style = {this._createStyleText(key)}>
    {key}
  </Text>
</View>
```